# std::istream_iterator<double> member variable fails while incrementing

Tags: c++, c++11, istream-iterator

I have a program as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

class Stream{
        public:
        //default constructor
        Stream();
        //constructor
        Stream(const std::string&);
        //Returns true if more elements are available
        bool hasNext();
        //Get the next element in the stream
        double getNext();
        private:
        std::istream_iterator<double> streamHandle;
        std::istream_iterator<double> eos;
};
Stream::Stream()
{
        streamHandle = std::istream_iterator<double>(std::cin);
}
Stream::Stream(const std::string& absolutePath)
{
        std::fstream file(absolutePath);
        streamHandle = std::istream_iterator<double>(file);
}
bool Stream::hasNext()
{
        return (streamHandle != eos)? true: false;
}
double Stream::getNext()
{
        double value = *streamHandle;
        ++streamHandle;
        return value;
}
int main()
{
   Stream input("test1");
   if( input.hasNext())
       std::cout << input.getNext();

}
```

While executing this program,it is core dumping.  I know it is happening only if it executes statement  `++streamHandle;`

So I implemented same functionality without using a class as follows and it works perfectly fine.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

void readFile(const std::string& absolutePath)
{
        std::fstream file(absolutePath);
        std::istream_iterator<double> streamHandle = std::istream_iterator<double>(file);
        std::istream_iterator<double> eos;

        while( streamHandle != eos)
        {
                double val= *streamHandle;
                ++streamHandle;
                std::cout << val << "\n";
        }
}
int main()
{
   readFile("test1");
}
```

Could you please help me to identify what is going wrong while creating a class  and iterate over `std::istream_iterator<double>` from the class.

Comment: Note that your `hasNext` and `getNext` can be simplified to `return streamHandle != eos;` and `return *streamHandle++;`, respectively

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem really lies in

```
Stream::Stream(const std::string& absolutePath)
{
        std::fstream file(absolutePath);
        streamHandle = std::istream_iterator<double>(file);
}
```

In the above constructor you create a local file stream and set the iterator to that.  Unfortunately when the constructor exits the file stream is destroyed which close the file and leaves the iterator in an invalid state.  Trying to use that iterator afterward is undefined behavior and cause the core dump.

Comment: Fixing this without simply passing in a stream could be tricky, too, since the stream could either be owning or non-owning depending on whether it's a file or `cin`. You could use a `std::variant<std::istream&, std::ifstream>` I suppose. A hackier way would be a `shared_ptr` that has a no-op deleter when initialized with `&std::cin`.

Comment: @chris or an `std::optional<std::ifstream>` member

Comment: @Caleth, How do you use `std::cin` with that?

Comment: @chris you don't. You initialise `streamHandle` as now, and the optional from the file in the `const std::string&` constructor. The default initialised optional is empty. The default destructor cleans it up properly

Comment: @Caleth, Oh. I see what you're getting at. Yeah, that works here since you need to store the iterator anyway.

Comment: Pass in a `shared_ptr<void> extra_resources`, which contains either nothing or a `shared_ptr<std::fstream>` depending on if you need it.